# Alternative way for using forms from ProjectA in ProjectB other than referencing method in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a scenario where in need to make use of the vb.net forms in ProjectA by other projects. All these projects are under single solution.

I know to achieve this by adding reference to ProjectA in other projects. Want to know if there are any other way to achieve this.

I basically want to eliminate the dependency on this DLL.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What are the restrictions that make the obvious solution not appropriate? We'd need to know that so as to avoid making suggestions that also run afoul of these odd restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to use the [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Managed Extensibility Framework or MEF is a library for creating lightweight, extensible applications. It allows application developers to discover and use extensions with no configuration required

However, this would require quite a lot of extra work and the creation of more assemblies (e.g. assemblies to contain interface definitions), so may be overkill for you here.